# How to parse the XML response from GeoCode an Address using Bing Services

Tags: windows-phone-7

say I got the response from Bing Services after GeoCoding an Address. I need the lat and longitude from this Xml response :

Example : XML response from Bing Service :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

 //--1--??

  string status = xdoc.Element......Element("status").Value;

   ValidateGeocodeResponseStatus(status, address);

    //--2- ???

  XElement locationElement = xdoc.Element()............Element("location");
```

How to parse by refering the Node ?  and get

1) The status code
2) The Lat/Lon

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting Status code

```
var status = (from resp in xdoc.Descendants("Response")
                         select resp.Element("StatusCode").Value).First();
```

Comment: How about the Latitude and longitude? How to travel down the node? Do I use element. element . element ... ?